# Why can I pass iterators of two different containers into sort?

Tags: c++

I was taking part in an online programming contest earlier today. There was a problem where I had to deal with three input vectors and one of them required sorting. My code, in a simple example, looked as follows:

```
vector <int> a;
vector <int> b;
.
.
.
sort(begin(a), end(b));
```

Notice how I mistakenly(/stupidly) made a typo `sort(begin(a), end(b)`. It took me quite a while to figure this error out because the runtime error message doesn't say anything about it.

```
c:\programming\mingw\mingw 9.2.0\include\c++\9.2.0\bits\stl_algo.h:4825:
In function:
    void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter =
    __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*,
    std::__cxx1998::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >,
    std::__debug::vector<int>, std::random_access_iterator_tag>]

Error: function requires a valid iterator range [__first, __last).

Objects involved in the operation:
    iterator "__first" @ 0x000000000023FDB0 {
      type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::__cxx1998::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >
(mutable iterator);
      state = dereferenceable (start-of-sequence);
      references sequence with type 'std::__debug::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' @ 0x0000000000
23FD10
    }
    iterator "__last" @ 0x000000000023FD80 {
      type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::__cxx1998::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >
(mutable iterator);
      state = past-the-end;
      references sequence with type 'std::__debug::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' @ 0x0000000000
23FCD0
    }

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

The only part I cared to look at was `Error: function requires a valid iterator range [__first, __last).` . I spent about 10 mins aimlessly thinking about what I'm doing wrong and though I glanced at the sort part a few times I failed to notice my stupid mistake. I didn't know that this was even possible (even though I've looked at the function definitions many times)!

So, my question: Why do C++ algorithms allow this and why hasn't the C++ committee done something about it? Why doesn't the compiler shout? Is it deliberately implemented this way to punish people making silly mistakes using C++ like all other things in C++?

Comment: "why hasn't the C++ committee done something about it?" If you know how to detect that range is invalid, you can submit your own proposal for next C++ standard. This possibility is not limited to the committees. Personally, I have no idea how could that be done. Iterator is pretty much disjoint from container it points to, you cannot check if iterators both point to the same container, if both are valid, etc. Also, since C++20 there are ranged versions of algorithms, using those you won't make a mistake of using iterators from different containers.

Comment: The compiler doesnt complain because the types are valid. Not sure what you expect the committee to do? That being said Microsoft's library in debug asserts that the iterators must be from the same container (I just tried it and got: `Expression: vector iterators in range are from different containers`) so it seems it depends on your library implementation.

Comment: _The only part I cared to look at_ But the rest of the message is provided by the runtime to help you in solving the problem. In this case, the "references sequence" lines end with the address of the container the iterators refer to. As those addresses are different, the iterators do not refer to the same container. Never ignore information provided by compiler or runtime messages.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That's how I ended up fixing the RTE. I was in a hurry and didn't notice the address part comprehensively at first and by the time I fixed it, it was already too late to make any valid submission :( I've never experienced this error before with sorting and didn't think it could happen either. Well, we learn from our mistakes and we learn something new everyday, right? Thanks.

Comment: Using better variable names is the way to make these problems more obvious, another bad habit that seems to be taught by competitive programming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why do C++ algorithms allow this and why hasn't the C++ committee done something about it?

Because it's not something that can be fixed.  Lets say you have an array like `int arr[500];` and you wan to sort it.  You would pass `arr` and `arr + 500` as the arguments to sort but those are just `int*`'s.  They hold no other information then the address they point to.  There is no way `sort` can check if those two pointers point to the same block of memory.

This is the same for iterators to standard containers.  iterators don't provide a way to access the container they come from, so `sort` can't check if the iterators point to the same object or not.

Comment: Oh, okay, That makes sense. I've only learned enough of the language to help me implement my idea of a problem in code, so this was something new to me. Thanks!

Comment: I would point out though that some iterators in Debug 'configuration' do provide some of this functionality. I just tested and MS's implementation asserts that both interators must be from the same container. So they seem to keep that information in the iterator. However I dont think the standard mandates anything regarding 'debugging functionality'.

Comment: @Borgleader You are correct, some implementations do this but it is not mandatory and mileage may vary.  I left it out as it's not mandated that you even get some helpful debugging.

Comment: @NathanOliver -- and those checks are rather heavyweight. In order to detect that two iterators point at elements of different containers, those iterators have to know what container they're associated with.

Comment: @PeteBecker What are you considering heavywiehgt?  For iterators, it would be as simple as storing a pointer to the container they are from and just doing a check of those pointers.  I wouldn't really consider that heavyweight, but it's definitely not free.

Comment: Oh, that would also need to be copied to all subsequent iterators so it would be "double" the cost for most operations.  I guess that could very well be heavyweight

Comment: Yes, it's simple, and it means that a plain old pointer can no longer serve as an iterator. The code can do tricks like using an internal function to implement the algorithm without checking iterator validity, and having the top-level algorithm validate the iterators and then call the internal function with the "real" (i.e., simpler) iterators. So it's possible to remove the extra (mostly unneeded) information by adding an extra layer of indirection and complexifying the code by having two different forms of iterators. You pays your money and you takes your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Why? Because otherwise you'd pay a runtime cost of checking what should be checked at compile time: the iterators would need to be annotated with the container they came from, and `sort` would need to check that.

In other words: Your valid complaint should be targeted not towards the C++ library, but towards the compiler that doesn't include a static check for this. A static code analyzer such as PVS-Studio would typically catch this. A static code analyzer will catch many more rookie mistakes that can cause lots of wasted time, so I'd suggest you equip yourself with one. Since I'm most familiar with PVS-Studio, I can tell you right away that it's [free for student use](https://www.viva64.com/en/for-students/).

Comment: When locally testing code, I wouldn't mind the extra overhead if sort had to check that, but that's just my personal opinion as I only code for the sake of solving problems for now. Maybe if the implementation in std::__debug had the functionality of doing so, it'd be great.

Comment: I did install it and wrote code with some possibly stupid errors. It seems to be great from first glance. Thanks!

Comment: @LostArrow I'm glad that you find it useful. It is a nifty tool, and many beginners shy from such tools. I wish someone made the same thing for problems in strength of materials and theory of elasticity. Those subjects were especially stupid-mistake-prone for me :)